# Blackberry Default browser - back button/ link

Tags: javascript, blackberry

I am searching for a way to go back to the previous page in the BlackBerry default browser for the 9860.

I tried the following commands, but none of them work. Can anyone give me valid javascript to do this on a BlackBerry 9860 and for any other BB OS >= 7?

```
window.history.back();

window.history.go(-1);

window.location = document.referrer;

navigator.app.backHistory();
```

Comment: will give bounty for the correct answer

Comment: it is, that was the first thing to check. Everything works except those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following sample page to play around with this behavior.  Check it out and let us know if you are seeing the same behavior:
http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/browser/window.html

window.history.go(-1) is generally the right way to be doing this.  Is it possible that an error is happening before the thread gets to this line?

If you are running BlackBerry 7, you can enable remote Web Inspector.  This tool could help identify any run time errors that might be occuring:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/web_inspector_overview_1553586_11.html